# MSDE vs SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, msde

There is a project that a developer is suggesting to use MSDE instead of SQL Server, I need to know the differences and limitations of MSDE to make sure it will be able to handle our project.

Comment: MSDE no longer exists. The current equivalent is SQL Server Express.

Comment: http://www.microsoft.com/express/Database/

Comment: This is a snarky comment for sure, but anyone recommending MSDE probably hasn't upgraded their sql skills since SQL Server 2000, so proceed with caution if they are your "SQL expert" (as you are doing) :) That said, SQL server express should be fine for most medium sized database applications with the main limitations on space (10 gigs for sql server 2008 R2) and cpus (only one)

Comment: Fire that developer. He has been living in cave.

Comment: ask him to come here and post his/her reasons as to why they  suggested to use msde... we'll set them straight ;)

Comment: As everyone else said, MSDE == SQL Server 2000. The "latest" version is SQL Server Express.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I remember well MSDE ( Microsoft Desktop Engine or something like that ) is the precursor of SQL Server 2005, 2008  Express Editions. MSDE does not come with a management tool like SQL Server 2008 R2 Express, for example. Also MSDE comes with some constraints that in 2011 are antique ( 1GB for database or 1GB RAM for the server that hosts the MSDE).
In conclusion , my advice is go with the latest SQL Server Express Edition.

Comment: MSDE = Microsoft Database Engine